# if IMAP CONDSTORE is not supported for Outlook/yahoo server, what is the alternative to get the flag changes from last check

Tags: outlook, imap, gmail-imap

I use highestModseq for gmail which will provide me the flag updates on emails. Additionally, am using emailjs-imap-client package. If anyone could help with the equivalent of highestModseq in outlook server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IMAP, there isn't one.  The equivalent is to ask for all the flags for all the messages since last time you synced.

For outlook, there's alternative protocols that may support smart access: EAS, EWS, or Outlook Mail API.  For Yahoo, you have to use the additional bandwidth and compute changes client side.

Comment: thank you so much for the information. Is there any way i could access the user details like User name and profile picture in IMAP?

Comment: Presumably you have the username from logging in.  There's no profile pictures, that's not part of email.  You'd have to use the provider's proprietary profile reading API (most likely HTTP based) to get that sort of thing.

Comment: @Max can you please post the IMAP command to "... ask for all the flags for all the messages since last time you synced"?

Comment: UID FETCH 1:* (FLAGS).  Grab all flags for all messages

Comment: Well, that's all flags. Not all flags that changed since last time you synced.

Comment: I was unclear.  I meant, grab all flags for all messages and compute the changes since last time you synced.